# React-Native pass useState to navigation Screen and updating FlatList

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to use react-navigation and pass useState between the screen, and having it render a flatlist.
It correctly updates the flatlist if i go back to the previous screen and then back to the commentscreen, meanwhile nothing happens when just pressing the button.

The setup is basically like this in my **App.js** file I have the following

```js
....
 <Stack.Screen
  name="CommentScreen"
  component={CommentScreen}
  options={{ title: "CommentScreen" }}
  initialParams={{ comments: getComments, setComments: setComments }}
  />
....
```

Where the comments are from the following

```js
...
var comments= [
    {
        comment_id: "1",
        post_id: "1",
        user: "user",
        comment: "comment1"
    }
]
const [getComments, setComments] = useState((comments));
...
```

Then in my **commentScreen.js** file i have the following, which is basically just a flatlist, an input field with a button to update the state with a new comment. Where the getter / setter is passed from App.js

```js
export default function CommentScreen({navigation, route}){

    const [currentComment, setCurrentComment] = useState("");
    const addComment = (message) => {
        route.params.setComments(
            [...route.params.comments,
                {
                    post_id: route.params.post_id,
                    comment_id: new_comment_id(),
                    user: "user1",
                    comment: message
                }
            ]
        );
      }
    return(
        <View style={styles.screenDefault}>
            <FlatList
                data={route.params.comments}
                renderItem={({item}) => Comment({item})} 
                keyExtractor={item => item.comment_id} 
                extraData={route.params.comments}
            />
            <View style={styles.comment}> 
                <View style={styles.inputField}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={{flex: 1}}
                        onChangeText={setCurrentComment}
                        placeholder=" Add comment "
                    />
                    <Button
                        style={{flex: 1}}
                        onPress={()=>addComment(currentComment)}
                        title="Post"
                        color="gray"
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

The renderItem function Comment is defined as follows in **Comment.js**

```js
export default function Comment({item}){
    return(
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        {item.user}
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.comment}>
        {item.comment}
      </Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
```

So something does happen, since if I go back and forth after adding a comment it shows up, but simply pressing the button nothing happens.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: React Navigation `initialParams` won't change after initialisation, hence the "initial". Updates to the comments won't trigger a rerender, but navigating back and forth does, that's why you're seeing a change at all. See also https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#what-should-be-in-params

Comment: @digitalbreed thanks for the answer, but how then would i go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use Redux, as it centralize your application state.
[React-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Here's how it works, imagine you have an app that contains two main screens, HomeScreen.js and OptionScreen.js.

1-Inside HomeScreen.js you have a View component

2-Inside OptionScreen.js you have a Button component

If we want to change the color of the **View** based on if **Button** is clicked or not, using useState, we will have to create a state for that color in the top parent component, which contains the two main screens, then pass it all the way down to the **Button** and **View** components, which is so messy and complicated.

Here's where Redux comes to play, we simply create a "state file" aside, and make the desired components listen to it.

**Button** clicked ---> state in redux changed to dark

state in redux changed ---> **View** will re-render and cause its color to change.